# WebView not shown in chrome inspector

Tags: android

I have an app that has a webview that loads some html & js local files, and I want to debug the webview.

I have set the `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)` in the webview activity, but the app does not shows in the `chrome://inspect/` page.

Is it because all are local files? Other apps with a webview do appear in the chrome inspector.

Comment: If the files are local has no influence. Do you enabled debugging for your App? Can you attach the debugger? Also the feature is only available for Kitkat and above.

Comment: yes, the app has enabled the debugging, and yes, I can attach the debugger (and confirmed that the code was running the `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` line)

Comment: Which device are you using? And which Android version? Did you try another device? Is the device listed in the page at all?

Comment: I've tried with a Samsung S7 running android 7, a Nexus 5X wunning android 8, and a Moto G5 Plus running android 7. All devices were listed, and other apps using webviews were listed too, the only one missing is this one. I though that it could be due to using local files, but if you say that it has no influence... I'm blank now.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works. Currently I am working in react native:

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.yourpackage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }  
}
```

After adding `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`  and importing `WebView`. Go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`. **Make** sure web view content is **open** in your app otherwise it won't show in the browser. If web view content is **open** then it will `show` inspect option

Comment: Where's `SplashScreen.show(this);` coming from? I'm getting an error `error: cannot find symbol
        SplashScreen.show(this);
`

Comment: Maybe you don't need this . I have updated my code. The only important line is `Webview.*`

Answer (score -6):

- Open Chrome and type chrome://inspect/#devices and you should see
  your device in the Remote Target List
- Click on the inspect to debug it.

For more details : [Remote Debugging WebViews](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Comment: That is what this is about, I go in there, and the device is listed, but not the app I am talking about. Other apps with webviews do appear.

Also, I have enable the usb debugging.

Comment: did you add the 2 Bot Code like in the link ?

Comment: Yes, the first this I did before asking was following all that steps.